# CocoaPods - using the pods in unit test project with link_with

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have two targets in my xcodeproj that is using CocoaPods but, by default the pods are only applied to the first.

I read that I should use the link_with command but this just causes errors, example:

```
platform :ios, 6.0

link_with ['Proj', 'ProjTests']

pod 'Reachability', '3.1.1'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '0.9'
pod 'FMDB', '2.1'
```

Results in

```
"syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
link_with ['Proj', ProjTests']"
```

How should this be written? I can't find any good examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit of trial and error required it seems, the link_with must be the first instruction. So,

```
link_with ['Proj', 'ProjTests']

platform :ios, 6.0

pod 'Reachability', '3.1.1'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '0.9'
pod 'FMDB', '2.1'
```

Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have quotes around 6.0 to make it `'6.0'` See the example here http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html